# Unable to retrieve the values in my cardTiles var

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable cardTiles in my angular 9 component.

I have defined the variable as

```
cardTitles:Product[] = [];
```

Product is defined as below

```
export class Product{
productName: string;}
```

When i console.log(this.cardTiles, "2") I get the screenshot below(ignore the first console log entry of undefined): 
[image]

I have tried accessing the items in the cardTiles var but I cannot.

I have tried cardTiles[0], cardTiles["0"], cardTiles[0][0], among others so maybe am not seeing something.

MyComponent.ts is as below

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProductService } from '../products/products.service';
import { Product } from '../products/products';

interface CardSettings {
  title: string;
  iconClass: string;
  type: string;
  amount: string;
  currency1: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-dashboard',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  cardTitles:Product[] = [];
  private alive = true;

  statusCards: string;

  commonStatusCardsSet: CardSettings[] = [
  ]

  statusCardsByThemes: {
    default: CardSettings[];
  } = {
    default: this.commonStatusCardsSet,
  };

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private themeService: NbThemeService) {

    this.themeService.getJsTheme()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(theme => {
        // get products
        this.productService._getProducts().subscribe(results => {

          this.cardTitles.push(results["payload"]);

        });
        //generate cards here
        this.statusCards = this.statusCardsByThemes[theme.name]; 

      });    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(this.cardTitles[0].productName);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please add your component and template code?

Comment: Please show where you are assigning and printing the value.

Comment: @MichaelD I am assigning it in the constructor method. And displaying it in the OnInit method.

Comment: @Prince, I have added the code.

Comment: Your mistake is that you think that if you called in in the contractor you already have it in OnInit.
well that not how it works. you can get it because you still dont have this array your trying to access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant access it because you still have undefined, you should do it like this:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProductService } from '../products/products.service';
import { Product } from '../products/products';

interface CardSettings {
  title: string;
  iconClass: string;
  type: string;
  amount: string;
  currency1: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-dashboard',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  cardTitles:Product[] = [];
  private alive = true;

  statusCards: string;

  commonStatusCardsSet: CardSettings[] = [
  ]

  statusCardsByThemes: {
    default: CardSettings[];
  } = {
    default: this.commonStatusCardsSet,
  };

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private themeService: NbThemeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.themeService.getJsTheme()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(theme => {
        // get products
        this.productService._getProducts().subscribe(results => {

          this.cardTitles.push(results["payload"]);
          // anyway what your doing here is not the best practice anyway. 
          this.onceIGetTheResult()
        });
        //generate cards here
        this.statusCards = this.statusCardsByThemes[theme.name]; 

      });    
  }

public onceIGetTheResult(): void {
    console.log(this.cardTitles[0].productName);
}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to access the contents of this.cardTitles elsewhere. From your answer, it's as simple as inserting the console.log() within the constructor method which I have been avoiding all along. 

Please refer to my question, I can access the values of this.cardTitles but not the inner values of what I'd pushed into the array.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your main problem, your pushing an array into array?
try doing it like this:
this.cardTitles = [...this.cardTitles, ...results["payload"]);
instead of this.cardTitles.push(results["payload"]);